# Separated subsets of $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Let $A$ and $B$ be separated subsets of some $\mathbb{R}^n$, suppose $a\in A, b\in B,$ and define $p(t)=(1-t)a+tb$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}^1$. Put $A_0=p^{-1}(A), B_0=p^{-1}(B)$.

(a) Prove that $A_0$ and $B_0$ are separated subsets of $\mathbb{R}^1$.

(b) Prove that exists $t_0\in(0,1)$ such that $p(t_0)\notin A\cup B$.

(c) Prove that every convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected.

**Proof:** (a) We'll prove that $\overline{A_0}\cap B_0=\varnothing$ and $\overline{B_0}\cap A_0=\varnothing$. Let $\overline{A_0}\cap B_0\neq\varnothing$. Then $\exists t_0\in \overline{A_0}\cap B_0$. If $t_0\in A_0\cap B_0$ then $p(t)\in A\cap B$. We got contradiction. If $t_0\in A_0'\cap B_0$ then $p(t_0)\in A'\cap B\subset \overline{A}\cap B$. Contradiction.

(b) Let for any $t_0\in[0,1]$ we have $p(t_0)\in A\cup B$. Put $F=\{t\in [0,1): p(t)\in A\}$ and $G=\{t\in (0,1]: p(t)\in B\}$. But $F\cup G=[0,1]$ and $F\subset A_0, G\subset B_0$. We got that $\overline{F}\cap G=\varnothing$ and $F\cap \overline{G}=\varnothing$. So we got that $[0,1]$ is disconnected which is not true.

(c) Let convex subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is disconnected. Then $C=A\cup B$ where $A,B\neq \varnothing$ and $A,B$ - separated sets. Taking $x\in A, y\in B$ then $p(t)=x(1-t)+yt\in C=A\cup B$. Let $A_0=p^{-1}(A), B_0=p^{-1}(B)$ then they are separated sets by (a). Then by (b) $\exists t_0\in (0,1)$ such that $p(t_0)\notin A\cup B=C$. We got contradiction with convexity of $C$.

Is my proof true?

P.S. Sorry for repeating.

Comment: Sounds correct to me :)

Comment: Can anyone answer is my proof true?